# Check internet connection or catch the exception?

Tags: android, android-wifi

I know how to check if the net is on or off, but I wonder if just catch the exception is fine too.

For example, in this piece of code I try to do a GET. If there is connection and the server is working then the method return `true`. If there is no connection (or the server is down, or whatever) the exception is thrown and returns `false`. So, in this simple scenario, Is it necessary to check the connection before do the GET?

```
private boolean get(String uri) {
  boolean success = false;
  try {
     HttpGet request = buildGet(uri);
     HttpResponse response = new DefaultHttpClient().execute(request);

     if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        if (entity != null) {
           /* DO SOMETHING */
           success = true;
        }
     }
  } catch (Exception e) {
     /* If we get here -> we can't do a GET request */
  }

  return success;
```

}

(Moreover, to check internet connection we need to add `ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE` permission)

Comment: This is a bad approach. Exceptions might be thrown not just because the network is down, but due to other reasons. For example, some code in `buildGet` might have a bug and throw a `NullPointerException`. That exception would be caught by you, so the code becomes harder to debug

Comment: you will saving your self from consuming  resource to try to connecting to network

Answer (score 0):

```
private boolean isNetworkConnected() {
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo ni = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (ni == null) {
            // There are no active networks.
            return false;
        } else
            return true;
    }
```

Comment: Yes, but I didn't ask that.

Answer (score 0):

It's usually better to check for connectivity before making the request. However, there are situations in which you should try to make the request and then handle the exception. An example is if your HTTP client has a caching layer and your GET request might be satisfied from cache without any network request.

In any case, if you're going to catch exceptions in your request, at least catch only IOException so that you don't accidentally catch other kinds of coding bugs.